# Is there any way to find argument type list of a function in php?

Tags: php, function, types, arguments

For example, look at this php code:

```php
class AuthController extends Controller {
   public function store(LoginRequest $request, int $id) {
      // code...
   }
}
```

And I wanna get the argument type list for the method `AuthController::store()`.

For example, doing this:

```php
print_r(get_arg_types('AuthController::store'));
```

should return:

```
Array (
   [0] => LoginRequest
   [1] => int
)
```

Now, this `get_arg_types()` doesn't exist yet, but I want to create & use that. Is there an way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reflect the class, then the method, then the [parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionparameter.php).

```
<?php

class Controller {}

class AuthController extends Controller {
   public function store(LoginRequest $request, int $id) {
      // code...
   }
}

$ref = new ReflectionClass('AuthController');
$methods = $ref->getMethods();
$params = $methods[0]->getParameters();
foreach ($params as $param)
var_dump($param->getType()->getName());
```

Output

```
string(12) "LoginRequest"
string(3) "int"
```

[Teh Playground!](https://www.tehplayground.com/QozxODej9aKcaIZz)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you're looking for is called *Reflection*, and php has a whole range of functions to do such things.

Most likely this will get you on your way: [ReflectionMethod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php).
and here is [some more generic background info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php).